# Subset of an ndarray based on another array

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have an array of ints, they need to be grouped by 4 each. I'd also like to select them based on another criterion, `start < t < stop`. I tried

```
data[group].reshape((-1,4))[start < t < stop]
```

but that complains about the `start < t < stop` because that's hardcoded syntax. Can I somehow intersect the two arrays from `start < t` and `t < stop`?

Comment: What are start, stop, and t?  Is one or more of them supposed to take the values of some vector?

Comment: `t` is an array of numbers, `start` and `stop` are both numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right way of boolean indexing for an `array` should be like this:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a=np.random.randint(0,20,size=24)
>>> b=np.arange(24)
>>> b[(8<a)&(a<15)] #rather than 8<a<15
array([ 3,  5,  6, 11, 13, 16, 17, 18, 20, 21, 22, 23])
```

But you may not be able to reshape the resulting array into a shape of `(-1,4)`, it is a coincidence that the resulting array here contains 3*4 elements.

EDIT, now I understand your OP better. You always reshape `data[group]` first, right?:

```
>>> b=np.arange(96)
>>> b.reshape((-1,4))[(8<a)&(a<15)]
array([[12, 13, 14, 15],
       [20, 21, 22, 23],
       [24, 25, 26, 27],
       [44, 45, 46, 47],
       [52, 53, 54, 55],
       [64, 65, 66, 67],
       [68, 69, 70, 71],
       [72, 73, 74, 75],
       [80, 81, 82, 83],
       [84, 85, 86, 87],
       [88, 89, 90, 91],
       [92, 93, 94, 95]])
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.arange(32)
t = np.arange(300, 364, 2)
start = 310
stop = 352
mask = np.logical_and(start < t, t < stop)
print mask
print arr[mask].reshape((-1,4))
```

I did the masking before the reshaping, not sure if that's what you wanted.  The key part is probably the logical_and().